# how to load data to many comboboxes from 1 database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

i had 2 `comboboxes` and i i get datasource for 1 table, but when select data form `combobox1` the `combobox2` also change same as `combobox1`, i want to select its with different value.

```
cn.Open()
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Table_Illness"
    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql1, cn)
    da.Fill(Dataset, "Table_Illness")
    beforillnessComboBox.DataSource = Dataset.Tables("Table_Illness")
    beforillnessComboBox.DisplayMember = ("Illness_Name")
    beforillnessComboBox.ValueMember = ("Illness_ID")

    afterillnessComboBox.DataSource = Dataset.Tables("Table_Illness")
    afterillnessComboBox.DisplayMember = ("Illness_Name")
    afterillnessComboBox.ValueMember = ("Illness_ID")
    cn.Close()
```

Comment: web or windows? also do you have any postback or selected index changed code that effects the combos as the above looks fine?

Comment: there is no error . but when i select `beforillnessComboBox` the `afterillnessComboBox` also change

Comment: its because you are filling the `comboboxes` with same `dataset` the solution is create another dataset for `comboboxes2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a different [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your combos

```
Dim bs = new BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = Dataset.Tables("Table_Illness")
beforillnessComboBox.DataSource = bs
beforillnessComboBox.DisplayMember = ("Illness_Name")
beforillnessComboBox.ValueMember = ("Illness_ID")

bs = new BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = Dataset.Tables("Table_Illness")
afterillnessComboBox.DataSource = bs
afterillnessComboBox.DataSource = Dataset.Tables("Table_Illness")
afterillnessComboBox.DisplayMember = ("Illness_Name")
afterillnessComboBox.ValueMember = ("Illness_ID")
```